# Passives used in differential signal lines

Tags: circuit-analysis, differential

My doubt pertains to the presence of passives in many differential links (say RS422, for eg).

Consider the schematic below -
[image: Circuit]

In the above circuits , I see a capacitor in series with the differential lines. What is the purpose of this ? In many cases I see a resistor and capacitor in series. [Resistor and capacitor in series](http://www.analog.com/library/analogDialogue/archives/46-04/AD46-04_BB_FIG_02.jpg).

Another common methodology is the one shown below - 
[image: Circuit].

It shows an RC and the junction between the caps being grounded. But, this is more like a single pole LPF to filter out high frequency components, right ?

Comment: In the first schematic the DC level is set by the 4 resistors on the right side of the cable. If there were no coupling capacitors at the left side (or at the other side of the cable, that would function also) then the DC level would be changed by the 2 resistors to +3.3 V on the left and anything else outside the drawn part of the circuit. The capacitors **separate** the DC levels so each side has it's own DC level which is desirable.

Comment: In the second circuit the capacitors are (together with the 10 ohms resistors) working as a lowpass filter (as it states in the schematic). This has nothing to do with the way the capacitors are used in the first schematic. Usually in the first schematic you want to use capacitors with a **large value** (to easily conduct the signal), in the second circuit you will want to use **small value** capacitors (so only high frequencies are attenuated).

Answer (score 2):

There is a big difference here. The top picture is a cable driver, cable and differential receiver. The bottom picture is a circuit that is used to differentially drive a local ADC.

The first scenario doesn't need to use capacitors to couple data to the twisted pair but, because it does, you could argue that the DC levels on the "send" end *might not always* match the required DC levels on the "receive end. In addition it can be firmly concluded that this type of data transmission is synchronous and different to RS232, RS485 or RS422 - those types of transmission are asynchronous AND dc connectivity MUST BE maintained because of the long periods of time that the line is idle.

The 2nd case (the ADC driver) is a very common circuit and is used as (or to supplement) an anti-alias filter.

Comment: "those types of transmission are asynchronous AND dc connectivity MUST BE maintained because of the long periods of time that the line is idle." - That was very enlightening. You nailed it as I had the same doubt. Thank u sir

Also, why do you say the sent and received levels are different ? In both ends its 3.3V signalling .

Comment: I'm saying "might not always match" - in the example you have shown they do match.

Answer (score 1):

In both situations, capacitors play the same role: they filter *common-mode* signal, which is an enemy No.1 in differential signal transmission. At every point in time, you want to have signal at one wire in the diff. pair to be an inverted other. This will not happen if one wire gets some externally coupled signal more than the other. So what do you do?

In your first diagram, the danger are those two pull-up resistors, so you eliminate DC components with two caps. In the 2nd, you get rid of high frequency components by those RC filters. But that series situations that you mention has nothing to do with filtering or noises - it is just a condition to drive a CAN bus receiver.

Comment: The capacitors will not filter out common mode noise. It is done using a common mode choke. Capacitors have an impedance and that is frequency dependant. So, if u place a capacitor, the best it can do is slightly attenuate or supress the amplitude of the CM noise and not filter it. Chokes will negate the effects of common mode noise as it is mutually coupled inductor and hence-forth magnetically nullify it.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Well, they will, if you consider DC a common mode noise.

Comment: Enemy #1 in differential signal transmission is differential noise AND NOT common mode noise. I think you are stretching it calling DC a common mode noise.